# The GRE Program discontinued the Computer Science Test

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

According to the ETS they have discontinued the computer science GRE test as of April 2013  https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/faq and there are some questions regarding the computer science GRE test and scores, should these questions be dealt with now (maybe by adding a header note to the question), or after five years as the scores will continue to be reportable for that period?

[Is a general GRE test required if I have already passed a GRE Subject Test?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/is-a-general-gre-test-required-if-i-have-already-passed-a-gre-subject-test)

[How much score in GRE computer science subject test is considered 'good'?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5032/how-much-score-in-gre-computer-science-subject-test-is-considered-good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as the scores can still be reported, then we should keep the questions as such, although we could of course add a note that the test can no longer be taken.

Comment: How can we add that note?

Comment: Well, if you have enough reputation points, you can directly edit the post to include a disclaimer at the top of the question. If not, you can still make the change, but it would need to be approved by a moderator.

Comment: One note: mass editing of such warnings would move all these posts to the top of the front-page, and flood it with these old questions… maybe we should do it on an as-needed basis

Comment: Excellent point. I would suggest that whenever such a question becomes active again, add the note. Also, we should probably add it already to the one or two most-viewed questions. That way we add it where the most eyeballs will see it.